# value of sinx + cosx + 3 greater than or less than 1

Tags: trigonometry

Is the value of the expression: 
sin(*x*) + cos(*x*) + 3 
 always more than *1*? I know how to graph it and see that this is true, but is there another way?

Comment: Plotting $\sin x + \cos x$.

Comment: Hint: Use "special" values of sine and cosine to rule out two of the possibilities.

Comment: range of this function is  $[ 3-\sqrt{2} ,  3+\sqrt{2}  ]$

Answer (score 4):

Use that $$\sin(x)+\cos(x)=\sqrt{2} \sin \left(x+\frac{\pi
   }{4}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Sketch a rough graph of cos(x) and sin(x). (The range of) both functions are always between -1 and 1.

(The range of) both sin(x) and cos(x) are never greater than 1 nor less than -1.

So therefore, for example, (the range of) 10 + sin(x) must always be between 9 and 11.

What does this tell you about (the range of) f(x) = sin(x) + cos(x) ?

Comment: maybe it tells you $\sin x + \cos x$ is at least $-2,$ but this argument per se doesn't tell you $\sin x + \cos x$ is strictly greater than $-2$ (which it is)

Comment: You're correct. However, your observation isn't needed to answer OP's question.

Comment: well, this doesn't tell you $\sin x+ \cos x+3$ is   more than $1$, just that it's greater than or equal to $1$

Comment: Ah yes that's true. Good point. My method would have been to find a single value, a, such that sin(a) + cos(a) + 3 < 2. But then we would only have determined 2 out of the 3 things in the OP. My method would work if the inequalities in the question were not strict, but since they are strict, I cannot guarantee sin(x) + cos(x) + 3 is strictly greater than 1, and so my method doesn't answer all parts of the question.